# Wordpress permalink / previous URL issue

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

My work has recently converted their website to run on Wordpress. The old website was made in ASP. Our marketing department have advertised a specific URL for an event, but now that URL has changed.

**The old URL is:** /who-are-you/stem-intro.aspx

**The new URL is:** /stem2014/

Can I used my htaccess file to make the first URL go to the second url without an .aspx file existing?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be performed easily with a 301 redirect in `.htacess`, especially if this is a one off thing

```
Redirect 301 /who-are-you/stem-intro.aspx http://www.YOURSITE.com/stem2014/
```

Comment: I tried using this method, it works but now I cant change the redirect url a second time, it wont update. Thoughts?

Comment: what do you mean by `change the redirect url a second time`?  are you trying to redirect two pages to the same page or..?

Comment: I added the recommended line to my .htaccess file - I accidentally missed a letter in the URL, realizing this after I uploaded the file, I went back and fixed the URL, re-uploaded the file and now the change wont take effect. The first time after uploading the change was instant.

Comment: @notchris This is probably because your browser is caching the .htaccess file. Try emptying your cache, using a different browser or visiting the .aspx URL in Private Browsing/Incognito mode.

Comment: @notchris, oh ok sorry i see now, yeah as James Thomas said, its most likely a caching issue, using a different browser, clearing your history, or using incognito are all possible ways to avoid the cache

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use this rule on top of your WP .htaccess (just below `RewriteEngine` line):

```
RewriteRule ^who-are-you/stem-intro\.aspx$ /stem2014/ [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: This answer is very helpful and correct, however, the below answer suits my needs better because it is used more for a temporary purpose.

Comment: You can choose any answer for you but in general one should not mix `mod_rewrite` rules with `mod_alias`. This is `mod_rewrite` based rule which is already in use by wordpress.